# Finding the height of a cone in terms of $R$ and $θ$

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry

The problem is:

> A right circular cone is made from a circular piece of paper of radius $R$ by cutting out a sector of angle $\theta$ radians and gluing the cut edges of the remaining piece together. Find the height $h$ of the cone in terms of $R$ and $\theta$.

In the problem before this one, you solve for $r$, which is the base of the cone.
$$
r = R\frac{2\pi - \theta}{2\pi}
$$

The method I've gone with is seeing that a right triangle is made from $h$, $r$ and $R$, Use the Pythagorean Theorem to find the value for $h$. Initially, it looks like this:
$$
h^2 = R^2 - \left( R\,\frac{2\pi - \theta}{2\pi} \right)^2
$$

When I follow through with the formula, I come to this step, and can't make any further progress:
$$
h = R + \left(-R\, \frac{-2\pi + \sqrt{4\pi\theta - \theta^2}}{2\pi} \right)
$$

The answer given is:
$$
h = R\, \frac{\sqrt{4\pi\theta - \theta^2}}{2π}
$$
Am I doing something wrong in applying the Pythagorean formula, or just using it incorrectly? I appreciate any advice or help given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two expressions are *almost* equivalent. If you used the other root with a minus sign in front of the square root in your answer, then break up the fraction into two pieces via the pattern
$$
\frac{A - B}{C} = \frac{A}{C} - \frac{B}{C}, 
$$
then there's a cancellation and your answer matches the given answer exactly.

---

There's an easier way to arrive at the answer (postponing the use of radicals until the end). Factoring $R$ out of the Pythagorean equation yields
\begin{align} 
h^2 
&= R^2 \Biggl( 1 - \biggl( \frac{2\pi - \theta}{2\pi} \biggr)^{\!2} \Biggr) \\
&= R^2 \, \frac{(2\pi)^2 - (2\pi - \theta)^2}{(2\pi)^2} \, \\
&= R^2 \, \frac{4\pi\theta - \theta^2}{(2\pi)^2}, 
\end{align}
and so since $h \geq 0$,
$$
h = R \, \frac{\sqrt{4\pi\theta - \theta^2}}{2\pi}, 
$$
in agreement with the given answer.

Comment: It is easier recognizing the ratio of angles subtended by same arc at cone apex and base circle center  equals $\sin \alpha,$ you need $\cos \alpha= \dfrac{h}{R}.$

Comment: @ Sammy Black: How do you deal with the negatives in the first solution? When I work it out, I get $h= R+ −R \frac{-2π}{2π}$
, which gives 2R  -A. S. ( I deleted my answer, Narasimham)